# Regarding the meaning of "over" in "over and over again"

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs

I am aware of the fact that the idiom:

> Over and over again.

means *repeatedly*. But which meaning of the adverb *over* is being used in the idiom above? does it mean "Throughout a period of time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have the sense of "throughout a period", much more "in its entirety".

The OED gives several very closely related uses, earliest from the 1400s.

- With a preceding numeral adverb, expressing repetition **He read it twice over**
- over again: a second time: **This is the old, old song over again.**
- over and over: repeatedly, many times over. Also over and over again. **The French played those two songs over and over again.**